# Java string replace using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have strings with values "Address Line1", "Address Line2" ... etc.
I want to add a space if there is any numeric value in the string like
"Address Line 1", "Address Line 2".

I can do this using contains and replace like this

```
String sample = "Address Line1";
if (sample.contains("1")) {
    sample = sample.replace("1"," 1");
}
```

But how can I do this using regex?

Comment: Do you want to add one more space if there is already a space before digit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sample = sample.replaceAll("\\d+"," $0");
```

Answer (score 3):

To use regex you will need `replaceAll` instead of `replace` method:

- as regex you can use

  - `\\d+` to match any group of one or more continues digits. We need all continues digits here because matching only one would create from `foo123` something like `foo 1 2 3`
  - `(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\d` if you want to add space **only before digit which has alphabetic character before it**. `(?<=\\[a-zA-Z])` part is [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) and it just checks if tested digit has character from range `a-z` or `A-Z` before it.
- and as replacement you can use `" $0` which means `space` and *match from group 0* which means part currently matched by regex.

So try with

```
sample = sample.replaceAll("\\d+", " $0")
```

or

```
sample = sample.replaceAll("(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\d", " $0")
```

which will change `"hello 1 world2"` into `"hello 1 world 2"` - notice that only `2` has additional space.

Comment: i agree, but would it be better to check if there is a character before it just in case? and put the space between both groups

Comment: You need to add regex group for that too

Comment: @EdwardM.B. I am in the middle of editing my answer to include this :)

Comment: @Pshemo to use reference to stored values in regex it's necessary to use groups. Should your regex be "(\\d+)" ?

Comment: @Fede `$0` is reference to group 0 which represents match from entire regex. I don't need any additional groups here.

Comment: @Fede I am glad you like it :)

Comment: I love look behind regex.

Answer (score 1):

First Create a Pattern Object of what you want to search and compile it in your case Pattern object will be as follows:-

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("1");
```

Now Create Matcher object for your string

```
Matcher m=p.matcher(sample);
```

Now put a condition to check if Matcher has found any your Pattern String and if it has put a replaceAll method to replace it

```
if(m.find())
{   
sample=m.replaceAll(" 1");
}
```

The Complete code is as follows:-

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
class demo
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String sample = "Address Line1";
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile("1");
    Matcher m=p.matcher(sample);
    if(m.find())
    {   
            sample=m.replaceAll(" 1");
    }
    System.out.println(sample);
}
}
```

Comment: There can be any digit.

Comment: I think the whole point of using regex was so the OP wouldn't have to have something separate for each number.